# How to transition an existing DB Schema without AUTO_INCREMENT primary key to a key with AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: hibernate, schema, primary-key, jpa-2.0, auto-increment

I have an application which was developed with HSQL DB and the problem is that we are migrating it to MySQL with JPA/Hibernate.
The problem is that the old schema doesn't have an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key : how can I use JPA to use such an incrementing key feature without modifying the schema ?

Is there a mechanism to tell hibernate to take the last INSERTED_ID + 1 for the next insertion ?

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

The safest is to use the mysql [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) when creating the table and if you want to start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

If you dont want to add this little modification to the schema while migrating to mysql. You can use the hibernate id generator `increment` that is constructed by counting from the maximum primary key value at startup.

**Really important !!! Increment is not safe for use in a cluster** compared to mysql AUTO_INCREMENT.

> **[IncrementGenerator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/id/IncrementGenerator.html)**
>
> An IdentifierGenerator that returns a long, constructed by counting
>   from the maximum primary key value at startup. Not safe for use in a
>   cluster!
>
> Mapping parameters supported, but not usually needed: tables, column.
>   (The tables parameter specified a comma-separated list of table
>   names.)
>
> **[increment](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)**
>
> generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only when no other process is 
>   inserting data into the same table. Do not use in a cluster.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your response.

I am not sure to understand how I can configure Hibernate to do that since I am using JPA xml mapping. Is there a way to configure the mapping to use a "hibernate HINT" like what you said ?

again thanks,